# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var displayed between (1) and (2) its a very odd error and it doesn't make sense at all.

```
if ($hiddenimage.length==0) { //if this is the first time moving over or clicking on the anchor link
    var $hiddenimage=$('<img src="'+this.href+'" />').appendTo($hiddenimagediv) //populate hidden div with enlarged image
    $hiddenimage.bind('loadevt', function(e){ //when enlarged image has fully loaded
        loadarea.empty().append($.thumbnailviewer2.buildimage($, $anchor, s, options)
        (1) - var $targetimage=$.thumbnailviewer2.buildimage($, $anchor, s, options) //create reference actual enlarged image
        (2) - $loadarea.empty().append($targetimage) //show enlarged image
        $.thumbnailviewer2.showimage($targetimage, s)
    })
```

Comment: The error is due to an unclosed parentheses .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Count the open parentheses on this line:

```
loadarea.empty( ).append($.thumbnailviewer2.buildimage($, $anchor, s, options)
              ^ ^       ^                             ^                      ^
              1 0       1                             2                      1
```

Add another closing paren; the parser thinks you're still specifying arguments to the `append()` function, and the `var` keyword is invalid in this context.

Also, use semicolons.  If not for your sake, do it for Douglas' health.

Comment: Thanks a lot I cant believe it was that easy, I didn't know you could use semicolons LOL

Comment: Use semicolons, and use an editor that will show you matching parens.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error message in the console with the minifier parsing my javascript source code. I found that using `// comments` like so always interrupted the minification process, and gave me an error in the console. Therefore i **switched** all `/* comments */` like so. [MDN Javascript Comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Comments) And immediately everything parsed as expected. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a big problem and can cause code in production not run at all.

Comment: Can't verify for production, may very well be. Voted on cdhowie's answer 

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because I have added '**,**'(comma) instead of '**;**'(semi-colon). IF you get this error, please re-check your code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was spacing when declaring variables. I had a javascript script that was getting loaded from our db dynamically on the page. I had copied the script and create a new entry for sql database. While, I copied the script, the copy action actually ignored the newlines (\n) or the select statement gave everything merged in a single line ignoring the newlines(\n). My javascript looked like this:

```
window.onload = function(){ var abc = 'xyz';}var xyz = 'abc';
```

The above script resulted in an error on console window:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'
```

The problem was near the closing curly brace near `var xyz` declaration as it has no space and it considers it as a wrong syntax. By adding some space and making sure there is semicolon at the end of each statement helped me clear the issues. Working script looked like this:

```
window.onload = function(){ var abc = 'xyz';}; var xyz = 'abc';
```